# Get relay chain blocknumber from parachain in substrate pallet

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

The title is quite self-explanatory, how can i get the blocknumber of the relay chain I'm connected to (Kusama) instead of my local blocknumber ?

All of this in a substrate/cumulus environment

Comment: From https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/279 and https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/320 my guess is that this is not currently possible and you can only read specific keys from the relay-chain into the parachain, as noted in https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_primitives_core/relay_chain/v2/well_known_keys/index.html

Comment: Just a tip: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ is far more active for questions like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you mean not Substrate, but Cumulus, to be specific, since you are talking about parachains.

Cumulus parachains' runtimes receive the so called [`PersistedValidationData`](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_primitives_core/struct.PersistedValidationData.html) from the collators. It has several pieces of information passed by the relay-chain. It does include `relay_parent_number`. That is the relay chain block number from which the parachain block in question was created.

In a cumulus parachain runtime, `PersistedValidationData` can be accessed through the [`validation_data`](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_pallet_parachain_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.validation_data) getter.

Be advised, this data is submitted by a collator in an inherent. That means, among other things, this data is not available in the `on_initialize` hooks.

Comment: Okay, i see, so the solution would be to either do what i want in `on_finalize()` (i do a lot of transactions), or save the blocknumber when `on_finalize()` and read it in `on_initialize()` to do what i have to.. What do you think ?

Comment: There are several things you can do. One of them is to set the callback OnSystemEvent https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_pallet_parachain_system/pallet/trait.Config.html . That would allow you to execute some code just right after the validation data is set

Comment: Another option is to introduce your own inherent that executes after the parachain-system’s one.